# Add +2 or -6 to the current GMT? (iphone)

Tags: objective-c, nsdate, nsdateformatter

i would like to create a tableView with different name of cities, and by clicking on each we can have the current time, i was thinking that i could put the GMT time and change it depending on the cell (the name of the city) we clicked : and thus, add +2 to the GMT hour, or -6 to the GMT. Do you think this could be possible?

I have this code for now, but i'm looking for some advices to create the "+2" or "-6" to this code : (this code is located in a method, updated every second to have the hour-minute-second updated)

```
NSDate *myDate = [NSDate date];
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"GMT"]];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-YYYY"];
NSString *GMTDateString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate: myDate];
[dateFormatter release];
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 9, accepted):

So, you want do display current time in different time zones?
You can pass different time zones to dateFormatter and it'll convert date to that time zone and return it to you.

```
[dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"GMT"]];
[dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:3600*2]]; // GMT+2
[dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:-3600*6]]; // GMT-6
```

Comment: hi, i'd like to use a variable instead of "2", or "6", can you tell me how i can make an operation like : NSNumber *num = [NSNumber numberWithInt:ws.gmt*3600]; and then :  [dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", num] ]]; ? this doesn't work, it says : invalid operands to binary ... Thanks a lot

Comment: `NSInteger offset = ws.gmt*3600;`  `[NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:offset]`

Comment: hi, thanks but it still says the same error with those lines, or with a simple "int". Do you have another idea?

Comment: hi evgeniy, do you have any idea for my question? thanks again

Comment: If you get error, then your variable is not int. Check what you're doing, I can't do that for you without access to your code. This snippet works fine.

Answer (score 2):

Use the date formatter for this. You just set the timezone and then you can get correct dates.

```
//-6 hours
[dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:-21600]];
//+2 hours
[dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:7200]];
```

If you would like to account for Daylight Savings use a named time zone instead of -6.

Comment: thanks for the answer! what "name" can i put for this? Thanks again